# Windows CMD / BATCH Command - FC command showing matching above/below lines

Tags: batch-file, cmd, difference

I want to compare 2 text files using cmd.exe's `fc` command. However, it is printing the line above and line below of the mismatched line too. How do I suppress this behaviour?

**a.txt**

```
32=10500.3000000
31=5252.8095
30=XXXX
75=20170208 00:32:40
6=5252.8095
60=20170208-00:00:03
```

**b.txt**

```
32=10500.3000000
31=5252.8095
30=YYYY
75=20170208 00:32:40
6=5252.8095
60=20170208-00:00:03
```

**Command** - `fc /l /n /c /t /lb200 a.txt b.txt1`

**Output**
Comparing files a.txt and B.TXT

```
***** a.txt
    2:  31=5252.8095
    3:  30=XXXX
    4:  75=20170208 00:32:40
***** B.TXT
    2:  31=5252.8095
    3:  30=YYYY
    4:  75=20170208 00:32:40
*****
```

**What I Want**

```
***** a.txt
    3:  30=XXXX
***** B.TXT
    3:  30=YYYY
*****
```

Comment: This is not possible without using a `for /f` loop around the command or a 3rd party utility

Comment: for loop to compare line by line?

Comment: `for /f` loop to remove the first line before and after every occurrence of `*****`

Comment: As long as there is only a single block with the same number of lines that differs, you can use `for /F` to search the `*****` lines and remove equal lines in between, or you can rely on the line numbers for synchronisation and also use `for /F`; however, as soon as lines within one file have been added/moved/deleted with respect to the other one, or there are multiple differing blocks, there is no chance to reliably remove matching lines of `fc` using `for /F`...

Comment: See [FComp.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3968): _"This Batch program take FC output and rearrange it in a way that is much more pleasant to read.The program identify new sections added between two lines of original file, or sections deleted from original file, or sections that was modified in any other way (updated) and display them in a format that allows you to identify each case in an easy way"_.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as a starting point

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=: eol=*" %%a in ('
        fc /l /n /t /c 1.txt 2.txt 
    ') do (
        if defined _%%a (
            set "line=%%b"
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            if not !_%%a!==!line! (
                echo(%%a: !_%%a!
                echo(%%a: !line!
                echo(
            )
            endlocal
            set "_%%a="
        ) else set "_%%a=%%b"
    )
```

While processing the output of the `fc` command, a variable is defined for each line number. When the same line number is found the content of the variable is compared against the new line and if they differ the two lines are echoed.

Comment: Thanks. I did try something similar but it is a very hardcoded sort of workaround. In case of missing/additional lines in text files, I would miss these differences.

Comment: @PankajJaju, You are right, `fc` is very limited and this code just inherits its limitations. Anyway, for small range of differences `fc` should be enough

Comment: @MCND IS there a way to make this script separate new lines and old lines? In other words, any lines that are not in the first file but are in the second would go into a file `new.txt` and any lines that were in the first file but are not in the second would go to `old.txt` ?

Answer (score 1):

Even if off topic to the selected tags, in these cases I'd always recommend a tool like windiff or [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/downloads) with a side by side comparison. See also [Gui-diff-tools](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/diffs/) . Some editors offer a similar option like TextPad.
[image: Winmerge]

Comment: Used WinMerge, selected Tools -> Generate Patch from the menu, done!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the output format of the [`fc` command](https://ss64.com/nt/fc.html) cannot be configured as you wished.

The following script simply searches for lines that begin with `*****` and just skips every line immediately before or after those, except for the very first line, which is never skipped. Of course there can be a lot of situations where this approach fails, but for simple differing blocks it should work fine as long as `fc` is able to synchronise (so an adequate number must be specified for the `/LB` option):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem /* Initialise variables, then loop over output of `fc` command,
rem    with all command line arguments simply forwarded to `fc`: */
set "LINE=" & set "PREV=" & for /F "delims=" %%L in ('fc %*') do (
    rem // This query is needed to skip lines after `*****`:
    if not defined PREV (
        rem /* This is just to not skip the very first line; just
        rem    comment it out if you do want to skip this line: */
        if not defined LINE echo(%%L
        rem // Store current line for next loop iteration:
        set "PREV=%%L"
    ) else (
        rem // Store current line:
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Check if current line begins with `*****`:
        if "!LINE:~,5!" == "*****" (
            rem // Return current line but not the previous one:
            echo(!LINE!
            endlocal
            set "PREV=%%L"
        ) else (
            rem /* Current line does not begin with `*****`,
            rem    so check whether previous line does: */
            if "!PREV:~,5!" == "*****" (
                endlocal
                rem /* Previous line begins with `*****`, hence
                rem    clear buffer for previous line in order to
                rem    let the following line be skipped then: */
                set "PREV="
            ) else (
                rem /* Neither the current nor the previous lines
                rem    begin with `*****`, so return the latter: */
                echo(!PREV!
                endlocal
                set "PREV=%%L"
            )
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Supposing the script is called `filecomp.bat`, simply call it with all the parameters just like you would call `fc`, so for example:

```cmd
filecomp.bat /L /N /C /T /LB200 "a.txt" "b.txt"
```

The output would be the following, based on your sample data and given that the batch file as well as the sample data files are all located in the current working directory:

> ```cmd
> Comparing files a.txt and B.TXT
> ***** a.txt
>     3:  30=XXXX
> ***** B.TXT
>     3:  30=YYYY
> *****
> ```